# Do bonuses to grappling CMD apply to enemy's rolls to escape grapple?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, grapple, combat-maneuver

Human alternate fighter favored class bonus states:

> Add +1 to the fighter’s CMD when **resisting** two combat maneuvers of the
> character’s choice.

If I want to make one of the choices to be grapple combat maneuver, does the bonus apply

- **only** when my character is the target, being grappled and on the defensive
- Same as above, but also **against the enemy's rolls** attempting to escape when my character is the grappler?

Usually any other combat maneuver is completely done after being targeted, but grappling has two participants each making continual rolls and both using CMB and CMD. The confusing part here is the word "Resisting" in the favored class bonus, as that would indicate only when you are being targeted.

Comment: Are you asking a question about Favored Class bonus to CMD or about bonuses to Grappling CMD?

Comment: @Ifusaso I tried to clarify the question. It is about grappling CMD bonuses, and if they apply in ALL situations, or just when you are being the one grappled and on the defensive.

Answer (score 4):

This works whenever you're on the defensive, i.e. *NOT* rolling the dice. So it'll work when someone attempts to grapple you, when someone else attempts to maintain or escape a grapple, or when they try to pin you.

It doesn't apply when you attempt to reverse or escape a grapple.

The bonus will work both for resisting enemy grapples, and to prevent enemies from reversing (or escaping) them. Both of these are grappling combat maneuvers, and any bonus will apply against both unless is specifically says otherwise.

Comment: This doesn't (directly) address the question regarding an opponent attempting to escape a grapple.

Comment: When the opponent is doing that, you aren't rolling the dice, therefore it helps. But I'll add it explicitly.

Comment: I meant when the opponent is trying to escape the grapple, which would be part of the first section (the same as reversing) but it would be good to add to the list.

Comment: That means they're rolling the dice. And I just included it an hour ago? "... when someone else attempts to maintain **or escape** a grapple...."

Comment: Sorry I must have read right over it

Comment: Ah, it happens.